# node.js + postgres: Syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am having trouble understanding the npm package pg and its "dynamic statements".

I want to be able to generate INSERT INTO statements but I only get syntax error in return

```
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = 'postgres://postgres@localhost/db';

pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }

  var queryConfig = {
    text: 'INSERT INTO users($1, $2, $3) VALUES($4, $5, $6);',
    values: ['username', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'ab', 'A', 'B']
  };

  client.query(queryConfig, function (err, result) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    done();
  });
});
```

The error I get is:

```
{ [error: syntax error at or near "$1"]
  name: 'error',
  length: 84,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '19',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1053',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror' }
```

Can anybody help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Databases generally don't let you use placeholders for identifiers (table names, column names, ...). PostgreSQL is complaining because you're trying to use the first three placeholders as column names:

```
INSERT INTO users($1, $2, $3) ...
```

You can think of identifiers like variable names in JavaScript: you can't put a variable name into another variable without some sort of `eval` chicanery. Similarly, you can't put a column name in a placeholder.

You should specify the column names without placeholders:

```
var queryConfig = {
  text: 'INSERT INTO users(username, firstname, lastname) VALUES($1, $2, $3);',
  values: ['ab', 'A', 'B']
};
```

Comment: Cewl, I was thinking it was something like that. Thx mu!

Comment: Does this mean the following query is invalid as well?


'UPDATE $1 SET $2 = $3 WHERE $4 = $5',[rec.tablename, rec.cell_d, rec.cell_v, rec.where_d, rec.where_v]

Comment: @KentWong Yes, you can't use placeholders for identifiers (i.e. table names, column names, ...), placeholders only work with values. So `$1`, `$2`, and `$4` wouldn't work there.

Comment: Okay, but what if you need the table name to be dynamic?

Comment: @U2ros Then you're stuck with string manipulation. The database interface should have a method for quoting/escaping identifiers that you'd use to make the dynamic table name safe or you could whitelist the table name to only allow known safe values.

Comment: Since my identifiers are dynamic, I'm still vulnerable to SQL injection. What now?

Comment: @KFunk As I said above, look for a "quote identifier" function in the database interface, then you'll be able to properly quote things and avoid injection issues. Alternatively, whitelist the identifiers.